# How to use the package "kinect_2d_scanner"?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Who can use the package "kinect_2d_scanner"?

After I compiled the package with "make",it shows as below:

Package mrpt-base was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `mrpt-base.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable No package 'mrpt-base' found Package mrpt-bayes was not found in the pkg-config search path. Perhaps you should add the directory containing` mrpt-bayes.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'mrpt-bayes' found
Package mrpt-slam was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `mrpt-slam.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable No package 'mrpt-slam' found Package mrpt-detectors was not found in the pkg-config search path. Perhaps you should add the directory containing` mrpt-detectors.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'mrpt-detectors' found
Package mrpt-graphs was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `mrpt-graphs.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable No package 'mrpt-graphs' found Package mrpt-graphslam was not found in the pkg-config search path. Perhaps you should add the directory containing` mrpt-graphslam.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'mrpt-graphslam' found
Package mrpt-hmtslam was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `mrpt-hmtslam.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable No package 'mrpt-hmtslam' found Package mrpt-reactivenav was not found in the pkg-config search path. Perhaps you should add the directory containing` mrpt-reactivenav.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'mrpt-reactivenav' found
Package mrpt-scanmatching was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `mrpt-scanmatching.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable No package 'mrpt-scanmatching' found Package mrpt-scanmatching was not found in the pkg-config search path. Perhaps you should add the directory containing` mrpt-scanmatching.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'mrpt-scanmatching' found
Package mrpt-topography was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `mrpt-topography.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable No package 'mrpt-topography' found Package mrpt-vision was not found in the pkg-config search path. Perhaps you should add the directory containing` mrpt-vision.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'mrpt-vision' found
Package mrpt-maps was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `mrpt-maps.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable No package 'mrpt-maps' found Package mrpt-hwdrivers was not found in the pkg-config search path. Perhaps you should add the directory containing` mrpt-hwdrivers.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'mrpt-hwdrivers' found
[rospack] warning: got non-zero exit status from executing backquote expression "ret="`pkg-config mrpt-base mrpt-bayes mrpt-slam mrpt-detectors mrpt-graphs mrpt-graphslam mrpt-hmtslam mrpt-reactivenav mrpt-scanmatching mrpt-scanmatching mrpt-topography mrpt-vision mrpt-maps mrpt-hwdrivers --cflags`" && echo $ret" in [/home/sven/ros_workspace/mrpt/trunk/mrpt_common/mrpt_libs/manifest.xml]
[rospack] error in backquote expansion for kinect_2d_scanner

CMake Error at /opt/ros/electric/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129 (message):

Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package
'kinect_2d_scanner'.  Look above for errors from rospack itself.  Aborting.
Please fix the broken dependency!

Call Stack (most recent call first):
/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:230 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
CMakeLists.txt:5 (rosbuild_init)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
make: *** [all] Error 1

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48612/how-to-use-the-package-%22kinect_2d_scanner%22?/) by [sven_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/1417/sven_007/) on ROS Answers with karma: 49 on 2012-11-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I didnt use that packagage but I assume u want to get a fake laserscan out of the kinect?

If I assume right you can use the node "depthimage_to_laserscan"

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-depthimage-to-laserscan
```

and then start the node with the param:

```
<launch>
    <include file="$(find openni_launch)/launch/openni.launch"/>
    
    <node pkg="depthimage_to_laserscan" type="depthimage_to_laserscan" name="convert">
        <remap from="image" to="camera/depth/image_raw"/>
    </node>
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [felixwatzlawik](https://answers.ros.org/users/22115/felixwatzlawik/) with karma: 201 on 2015-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0